# Conditional rendering on button click

Tags: c#, .net, angularjs, conditional-statements

I have a webapp that has a c# backend and a Angular frontend. At the moment, I have a list of items; each item then has a list, one of the options on this list is "delete item". Right now the item can always be deleted but I have recently made a change on my database meaning if the item has child items, it cannot be deleted until the children items are deleted.

However, I am not very experienced with Angular and not sure how to go about this. I would like a popup that would say "Delete children items first".

Here is my backend code:

```
public async Task DeleteItem(string itemId)
{
    await PerformDbContextActionAsync(context =>
    {
        var sub = context.Subscriptions.FirstOrDefault(s => s.ItemUid.Equals(itemId, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
        if (context.Products.Include(a => a.Item).Any(a => a.Item.ItemUid.Equals(itemId)))
        {
            throw new Exception("A item cannot be deleted if it still contains child items");
        }

        if (sub == null) return;

        context.Products.Remove(sub);
        context.SaveChanges();
    });
}
```

And the Angular code:

```
<ul class="uib-dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="" ng-click="ctrl.showItem(sub.itemId)" id="viewLink"><i class="fa fa-user-times m-r-sm"></i>View</a></li>
    <li><a href="" ng-click="ctrl.editItem(sub.itemId, sub.itemName)" id="editLink"><i class="fa fa fa-sliders m-r-sm"></i>Edit</a></li>
    <li><a href="" ng-click="ctrl.deleteItem(sub.itemId)" id="deleteLink"><i class="fa fa-trash m-r-sm"></i>Delete</a></li>
</ul>
```

I know I need to pass an exception to the FE and then deal with it there but I am unsure how to firstly pass this to the FE and then to have a conditional render depending on whether there are child items or not.

Answer (score 0):

Throw exception will return HTTP 500 error, you have to catch the error in your angularjs HTTP requests and display a popup here is a sample code for angularjs

```
call_http() {
    this.http.delete('/api/goes/:id').then(data => {
      this.result = data;
    },
      err => {
       // display error in popup alert 
       alert(err);
       // check error status code is 500, if so, do some action
      });
  }
```